# Declare generic type of instance

Tags: c#, oop, generics, interface

How to declare variable that is for generic type of instance?

In controller, I need to create instance that depend on payment type, and each class has different type of parameter. That's why I used generic type.
But I don't know what type I need to set to define variable for each payment class.

Models for parameter

```
public class PaymentModel
{   
    public string orderNo { get; set;}
}

public class CCPaymentModel : PaymentModel
{
    public string CCNo {get; set;}
    public string expDate {get; set;}
}

public class PaypalPaymentModel : PaymentModel
{
    public string paypalID {get; set;}
}

public class GooglePaymentModel : PaymentModel
{
    public string googleID {get; set;}
}
```

Interface class, I use Generic type parameter because each payment type need different type of parameter.

```
public interface IPayment<T> where T : PaymentModel
{
    void makePayment(string orderNo);
    void makeRefund(T refundInfo);
}
```

Models,

```
public class SagePayment
    : IPayment<CreditCardPaymentInfo>
{
    public void MakePayment( CreditCardPaymentInfo creditCardPaymentInfo ) {
        // make payment
    }

    public void MakeRefund( CreditCardPaymentInfo creditCardPaymentInfo ) {
        // make refund
    }
}

public class GooglePayment
    : IPayment<GooglePaymentModel>
{
    public void MakePayment( GooglePaymentModel paymentInfo ) {
        // make payment
    }

    public void MakeRefund( GooglePaymentModel paymentInfo ) {
        // make refund
    }
}

public class PaypalPayment
    : IPayment<PayPalPaymentModel>
{
    public void MakePayment( PayPalPaymentModel paymentInfo ) {
        // make payment
    }

    public void MakeRefund( PayPalPaymentModel paymentInfo ) {
        // make refund
    }
}
```

Controller (Create instance)

```
public void Charge(string paytype,orderNo){

    IPayment<???> paymentProcess; // //Error    1   Using the generic type 'com.WebUI.Models.IPayment<T>' requires 1 type arguments
    Object payinfo;  //

    if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^Credit Card"))
    {
        paymentProcess = new SagePayment();
        payinfo = getPaymentInfo(paytype, orderNo); // it return CCPaymentModel type object
    }
    else if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^PayPal"))
    {
        paymentProcess = new PayPalPayment();
        payinfo = getPaymentInfo(paytype, orderNo); // it return PaypalPaymentModel type object
    }
    else if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^Google"))
    {
        paymentProcess = new GooglePayment();
        payinfo = getPaymentInfo(paytype, orderNo); // it return GooglePaymentModel type object
    }

    paymentProcess.MakePayment(payinfo);
}
```

To avoid error, I could this,

```
public void Charge(string paytype,orderNo){

    if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^Credit Card"))
    {
        IPayment<CCPaymentModel> paymentProcess = new SagePayment();
        payinfo = getPaymentInfo(paytype, orderNo);
        paymentProcess.MakePayment(payinfo);
    }
    else if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^PayPal"))
    {
        IPayment<PaypalPaymentModel> paymentProcess = new PayPalPayment();
        payinfo = getPaymentInfo(paytype, orderNo);
        paymentProcess.MakePayment(payinfo);
    }
    else if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^Google"))
    {
        IPayment<GooglePaymentModel> paymentProcess = new GooglePayment();
        payinfo = getPaymentInfo(paytype, orderNo);
        paymentProcess.MakePayment(payinfo);
    }
}

public void Refund(string paytype,orderNo){

    IPayment<???> paymentProcess; // //Error    1   Using the generic type 'com.WebUI.Models.IPayment<T>' requires 1 type arguments
    Object payinfo;  //

    if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^Credit Card"))
    {
        paymentProcess = new SagePayment();
        payinfo = getPaymentInfo(paytype, orderNo); // it return CCPaymentModel type object
    }
    else if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^PayPal"))
    {
        paymentProcess = new PayPalPayment();
        payinfo = getPaymentInfo(paytype, orderNo); // it return PaypalPaymentModel type object
    }
    else if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^Google"))
    {
        paymentProcess = new GooglePayment();
        payinfo = getPaymentInfo(paytype, orderNo); // it return GooglePaymentModel type object
    }

    paymentProcess.MakeRefund(payinfo);
}
```

But I know it is not right way.

Anybody know, please advice me.

Comment: @millimoose How restructure that design, could you explain a little more detail please? I am learning OOP now, so I'd like to know right way that could use in real project.

Comment: Generally, it is a design smell when you have this sort of 1:1 correspondency between sets of classes, **and** it's exposed to clients of these classes. This is something that should be hidden from the controller class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make `Charge()` and `getPaymentInfo()` be generic with respect to the type of `PaymentModel`:

```
void Charge<TPaymentModel>(...) where TPaymentModel : PaymentModel {
    IPayment<TPaymentModel> payment = GetPayment<TPaymentModel>();
    // ...
    payment.MakePayment(getPaymentInfo<TPaymentModel>(...));
}

IPayment<TPaymentModel> GetPayment<TPaymentModel>() where TPaymentModel : IPaymentModel
{
    // Create payment of appropriate type based on typeof(TPaymentModel)
}

TPaymentModel GetPaymentInfo(...) where TPaymentModel : PaymentModel
{
    // Create payment model of appropriate type based on typeof(TPaymentModel)
}
```

This is still a little ugly, to resolve this you could introduce a few new classes to hide the correspondence between the types from the interfaces and make the design more sound:

```
/// Abstracts over different ways of making payments
interface IPaymentMaker 
{
    void MakePayment(string payType, long orderNo);
    // MakeRefund etc.
}

/// Refactor code common to all payment types here, and handle the association 
/// between payment and payment model.
class PaymentMakerBase<TPaymentModel> : IPaymentMaker 
    where TPaymentModel : IPaymentModel 
{
    void MakePayment(string payType, long orderNo) 
    {
        NewPayment().MakePayment(NewPaymentModel(payType, orderNo));
    }

    abstract IPayment<TPaymentModel> NewPayment();
    abstract TPaymentModel NewPaymentModel(string payType, long orderNo);
}

/// Handle only the differences between payment types that can't be put inside their
/// implementations
class PaypalPaymentMaker : PaymentMakerBase<PaypalPayment> 
{
    IPayment<PaypalPayment> NewPayment() { ... }
    PaypalPayment NewPaymentModel(...) { ... }
}

static class PaymentMakerFactory 
{
    /// The only "not type safe" part, handles parsing the payType string and 
    /// resolving it to the correct `PaymentMaker`
    public IPaymentMaker GetPaymentMaker(string payType) 
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(payType, ...)) 
        {
            // return appropriate payment maker for the payType
        }
        else if (...) 
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then, your controller code only looks like this:

```
PaymentMakerFactory.GetPaymentMaker(payType).MakePayment(payType, orderNo);
```

Obviously the above design could be improved by removing redundancies (payType probably isn't needed everywhere I include it), making it more "objecty" (instead of passing identical argument lists around), or more convenient (`PaymentMakerFactory` could probably be changed into a *facade* that creates the right payment maker and then calls `MakePayment` right away).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am reading your answer 10 time now, :) but still hard to understand, I will read 100 time more. By the way, what is this for? NewPayment().MakePayment(NewPaymentModel(payType, orderNo));

Comment: @Expert I'd recommend putting the code into VS and clicking through it. It's functionally your code, just split up into multiple classes. Where I use `...`, that's code that's the same as you already have (and haven't listed in your question). Basically, the code you had in the controller now mostly lives in `PaymentMakerBase`. Except for the parts that are different for each payment type, those are in subclasses of `PaymentMakerBase`. `NewPayment().MakePayment(...)` corresponds to the contents of your `if (Regex.IsMatch(...))` clauses.

Answer (score 3):

Given that your `MakePayment` method does *not* require `T`, it would probably be simplest to declare that in a separate interface. You could either make the generic interface extend the non-generic one:

```
// Capitalization fixed to comply with conventions
public interface IPayment
{
    void MakePayment(string orderNo);
}

public interface IRefundPayment<T> : IPayment where T : PaymentModel
{
    void MakeRefund(T refundInfo);
}
```

Or just have them as separate interface:

```
public interface IPaymentHandler
{
    void MakePayment(string orderNo);
}

public interface IRefundHandler<T> where T : PaymentModel
{
    void MakeRefund(T refundInfo);
}
```

Either way, you then only need the non-generic interface in your `Charge` method.